# Trying to correctly format this string as it is bringing up a error

Tags: python

I have not 100% finished this question, but I would like somebody to correct the formatting of my print statement. And give guidance to finish this question.

```py
def display_variables_over_time(tn0, tp0, c0, percent_reduction, year_num):
    """Takes initial values for TN, TP, and CHLA and prints out a table
       showing how the values progress over time given they are all
       reduced by the given percentage per year."""
    
    num = 0
    
    print("Year", "TN", "TP", "CHLA")
    
    while num <= year_num:
        tn = tn0 / percent_reduction
        tp = tp0 / percent_reduction
        chila = c0 / percent_reduction 
        
        print("{:3d}, {:.10.2f}, {:10.2f}, {:10.2f}".format(num, tn, tp, chila))
        num += 1
    
display_variables_over_time(2048, 256, 128, 12.5, 5)
```

This is the output my code is supposed to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a wayward period.

`print("{:3d}, {:.10.2f}, {:10.2f}, {:10.2f}".format(num, tn, tp, chila))` vs

`print("{:3d}, {:10.2f}, {:10.2f}, {:10.2f}".format(num, tn, tp, chila))`

You can also remove the commas if you prefer the output (and space out the header):

`print("{:3d} {:10.2f} {:10.2f} {:10.2f}".format(num, tn, tp, chila))`

Answer (score 0):

you can format your header in following way:

```
print("{:10} {:10} {:10} {:10}".format("Year", "TN", "TP", "CHLA"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your `code`:-

- In Calculation
- In Printing Results:-

Let's discuss each scenario one by one.

**1. Calculation Mistake:-**

You have made the same mistake in the calculation of `TN`, `TP`, and `CHLA`. So, let's discuss the `mistake` you made and how to resolve it. So, I have taken `TN` and its first `iteration` for `Calculation`

```
# What you have done:-

# In Code:-
tn = tn0 / percent_reduction

# Mathematical result of above code:-
tn0 = 2048
percent_reduction = 12.5

tn = tn0 / percent_reduction
tn = 2048/ 12.5
tn = 163.84
```

So, as you can see we have encountered the wrong `Answer`. Because you are `dividing TN` with `percent_reduction` directly. So, to resolve this kindly follow the method given below:-

```
# What you have to do:-

# In Code:-
tn = ((total_percent - percent_reduction)*tn)/total_percent

# Mathematical result of above code:-
total_percent = 100
percent_reduction= 12.5
tn = 2048

total_percent                       ---> TN
(total_percent - percent_reduction) ---> (?)

          OR

100          ---> 2048
(100 - 12.5) ---> (?)

(?) = (87.5 * 2048)/100
(?) = 1792
```

As you can see we have got our `Correct` answer. So, we have to only `iterate` our `result`.

**2. Printing Mistake:-**

You can `print` result by `print("{} {:10.2f} {:10.2f} {:10.2f}".format(i, tn, tp, chla))` because if you can see `Year` is in `int` `datatype` and all the other fields are `decimal` followed by `2 decimal points`.

---

`Solution` of above scenarios with `code` stated below:-

```
# Declaration of 'display_variables_over_time' Function 
def display_variables_over_time(tn, tp, chla, percent_reduction, year):

    # Declaration of 'year_count' for printing 'result' within 'loop'
    year_count = year + 1

    # Declaration of 'total_percent' for calculation of 'TN', 'TP' and 'CHLA' after 'Percent_reduction'
    total_percent = 100

    print("{} {:11} {:10} {:10}".format("Year", "TN", "TP", "CHLA"))

    # 'For Loop' for Calculation of 'TN', 'TP', 'CHLA'
    for i in range(year_count):
        # Print Result
        print("{} {:10.2f} {:10.2f} {:10.2f}".format(i, tn, tp, chla))

        # Updation in the Value of 'TN', 'TP', 'CHLA' after 'percent_resuction'
        tn = ((total_percent - percent_reduction)*tn)/total_percent
        tp = ((total_percent - percent_reduction)*tp)/total_percent
        chla = ((total_percent - percent_reduction)*chla)/total_percent

# Initialization of 'display_variables_over_time' Function 
display_variables_over_time(2048, 256, 128, 12.5, 5)
```

```
# Output of above code:-
Year TN          TP         CHLA      
0    2048.00     256.00     128.00
1    1792.00     224.00     112.00
2    1568.00     196.00      98.00
3    1372.00     171.50      85.75
4    1200.50     150.06      75.03
5    1050.44     131.30      65.65
```

As you can see we have achieved our desired `Output`. Hope this solution helps you.